# NSDistantObject header missing

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I'm playing around with [some tutorials](http://www.damienlegrand.com/blog/article/Distributed-Objects-with-Java-Cocoa) on Distributed objects - I just tried to declare an NSDistantObject but got an 'Undeclared identifier' error. When I looked through the header files in the foundation framework, there is no header file for NSDistantObject, even though [Apple's own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroFoundation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000687-BAJDAJAG) lists it in that framework. Anyone know what's going on? I can't find anyone else with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see that the header is not available in the iOS SDK.